# Cached Infinite scrolling with varying height contents and hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

I am doing a feature in my existing MVC project, which is a floating panel common to all pages. This panel shows activities and info related to user logged in and the content is infinite scroll-able.

Basic infinite scrolling is possible, but I need to keep only those elements that are visible in view port. The rest needs to be cached to prevent DOM filled with lots of elements.

I have looked different plugins like iscroll.js, clusterize.js and infinity.js. But all seems to work with fixed height contents.

Is there any plugin which deals with variable height content i.e a plugin which recalculates the height of the cached contents according to changes in height or may be due to resize of the panel?

Comment: No one has yest responded!